# How to correctly get date and time passed between two dates?

Tags: delphi, datetime, delphi-xe6

I am creating this function:

```
function LiteralTimePassed(FromDate: TDateTime; ToDate: TDateTime = 0): string;
const
  Coma = ', ';
var
  Dt, Mt: Integer; { se dos dias contarem mais que 30/31 então aumenta o mês }
  P: TDateTime;
  HC: Boolean; { indica se já há um token antes do novo token, para colocar vírgula }
  Token: string; { a parte do timestamp verificada no loop }
  Literal: string;
  Y, M, D, H, N, S: Integer; { ano, mês, dia, hora, minuto(n), segundo }
  Ys, Ms, Ds, Hs, Ns, Ss: Boolean; { valida se valores maiores que 1 para adicionar 's' }
begin
{ retorna quanto tempo se passou desde a data 1 até a data 2 em forma literal }
  if ToDate = 0 then ToDate := Now;
  HC := False;
  Literal := '';
  P := ToDate-FromDate ;
   Dt := (DaysInMonth(FromDate)-DayOf(FromDate))+(DaysInMonth(ToDate)-DayOf(ToDate));
   Mt := Dt div DaysInMonth(ToDate);
  Ys := VarAssign(Y, YearsBetween(ToDate, FromDate)) > 1;
  Ms := VarAssign(M, (MonthsBetween(ToDate, FromDate)-(Y*MonthsPerYear))-Mt) > 1;
  Ds := VarAssign(D, Dt mod DaysInMonth(ToDate)) > 1;
  // I did not make the hour, minute and second, yet...
end;
```

To get a response like:

```
 There has been "2 years, 4 months, 1 day, 7 hours, 30 minutes and 22 seconds" between those dates
```

My doubt is if my logic is correct in the case of counting days passed and if I will have to make the same calculations with the time part.

But if you know any free coded that already does that, it will save me much time!

Thanks.

Comment: You can use TTimeSpan (located in System.TimeSpan) to do the time part. As it will give you the days only you have to do the months and years by your own code.

Comment: @UweRaabe could you write an answer explaining how to use TTimeSpan? It's not clear how to create and manipulate this object.

Comment: @EASI: Learn to read the source code. If you did so, you'd immediately see that `TTimeSpan` is not an *object*, it's a *record*, and it doesn't have to be created. (You'd also quickly see that you can use `TTimeSpan.Subtract(Date1, Date2: TDateTime)` to find the difference between two dates.) OR, **gasp** you could also see the [TTimeSpan documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/System.TimeSpan.TTimeSpan).

Comment: Sorry, didn't noticed it is a record.

Comment: In general terms TTimeSpan is an object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First deal with years and months, after that TTimeSpan:

```
procedure TimePassed(dt1,dt2: TDateTime);
var
  y1,m1,d1,h1,mi1,s1,ms,y2,m2,d2,h2,mi2,s2,y,mo,d:word;
  ts:TTimeSpan;
begin
  DecodeDateTime(dt1,y1,m1,d1,h1,mi1,s1,ms);
  DecodeDateTime(dt2,y2,m2,d2,h2,mi2,s2,ms);
  ms:=12*y2+m2-12*y1-m1;
  if s1+60*mi1+60*60*h1+24*60*60*d1>s2+60*mi2+60*60*h2+24*60*60*d2 then ms:=ms-1;
  mo:= ms mod 12;
  y:=ms div 12; //years and months ready, now the rest
  dt1:=EncodeDateTime(y1+y,m1+mo,d1,h1,mi1,s1,0);
  ts := TTimeSpan.Subtract(dt2, dt1);
  Result:= Format('There has been "%d years, %d months, %d days, %d hours, %d minutes and %d seconds" between those dates',
    [y,mo,ts.Days, ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds]);
end;
```

Answer (score 4):

Regarding the day and time part you can ease your life with TTimeSpan found in System.TimeSpan:

```
var
  ts: TTimeSpan;
begin
  ts := TTimeSpan.Subtract(ToDate, FromDate);
  Format('There has been "%d days, %d hours, %d minutes and %d seconds" between those dates',     
    [ts.Days, ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds]);
end;
```

This will not solve the year, month part, though.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the following logic:

```
Y := YearsBetween(FromDate, ToDate);
FromDate := IncYear(FromDate, Y);

M := MonthsBetween(FromDate, ToDate);
FromDate := IncMonth(FromDate, M);

and so on
```

Comment: Is it not better to use MonthsSpan?

Comment: MonthsSpan gives only rough approximation

Comment: Sorry, I just found that MonthsBetween uses approximation too :(  Will delete my answer soon.